# <p> tag breaks shortcode output (other solutions don't work)

Tags: plugins, shortcode, wp-autop

I just encountered weird problem.
My shortcode output which is something like

```
'<span class="link_container"><a href="#">'.$content.'</a></span>    
<div class="upgrade_box">
some more divs here
</div>'
```

is being broken by random `</p>` closing tag inserted after `</span>`

Changing wpautop priority didn't work. The only solution that seemed to work was removing 
wpautop filter altogether which is obviously not that great of a solution.

P.S. I'm using wp 2015 theme on my testing site so it's not some theme forest theme ppl seem to have problems with.

Comment: _Why_ was it broken? Could you provide complete example of variable's content and such?

Comment: I assume because returned value of shortcode (mentioned in question) is passed through wpautop for some weird reason and since div shouldn't be inside p tag, it closes p right before div?

Comment: What does your actual shortcode look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this function out, be sure to add your shortcode in the array

```
// (OPT) STOP SHORTCODES THAT DON'T USE INLINE CONTENT FROM BEING WRAPPED IN A P TAG (until WP fixes this)

// ** NOTE -> BE SURE TO change the array to the shortcodes you are using!

add_filter('the_content', 'the_content_filter');
function the_content_filter($content) {
    // array of custom shortcodes requiring the fix
    $block = join("|",array( 'shortcode_name' ));
    // opening tag
    $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[($block)(\s[^\]]+)?\](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[$2$3]",$content);
    // closing tag
    $rep = preg_replace("/(<p>)?\[\/($block)](<\/p>|<br \/>)?/","[/$2]",$rep);
    return $rep;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: can you include the function you used to create your shortcode?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6RjvwY2J . Part that returns shortcode output

Comment: you are adding the shortcode like so correct? and added the shortcode_name section to the function above `add_shortcode( 'shortcode_name', 'coupg_shortcode_handler' );`

Comment: yes, that is right

Comment: did you try this solution http://sww.nz/solution-to-wordpress-adding-br-and-p-tags-around-shortcodes/ thats what I used before finding the function above

Comment: yeah, I tried that. It did nothing

Answer (score 0):

Going off @nickfmc's comment, here is a revised version for latest WordPress that uses the correct priority on the filter and also fixes a couple issues with the regex.

Note: it is best to keep each block format shortcode on its own line (separate paragraph in WYSIWYG editor).

```
<?php

add_filter('the_content', function ($content) {
    $blocks = 'columns|column';

    $replace = [
        "/(?:<p>)?\[($blocks)(\s[^\]]+)?\](?:<\/p>|<br\s*\/?>)?/" => '[$1$2]',
        "/(?:<p>)?\[\/($blocks)\](?:<\/p>|<br\s*\/?>)?/" => '[/$1]',
    ];

    return preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $content);
}, '10.1');
```

Of course, replace the `$blocks` variable with your own shortcodes.